# Ajax Request, automatically receive data every 30 seconds (with a number of users using the website simultaneously)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have ajax request below - where it will get a number of pledges (tiles) by users in which when there's a pledge, the tile will flip and show:

```
var reveal = 0;
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
dataType: "json",
url: '/Services/getpledge.ashx',
success: function (data) {
  if (data.status === "Success") {
    $.each(data.Pledges, function (i, v) {
      if (typeof v.TileID !== 'undefined') {
        jQuery('.square-container div[data-id=' + v.TileID + ']').find('.front div').removeClass('box1').addClass('box3');
        jQuery('.square-container div[data-id=' + v.TileID + ']').parent().addClass('complete');
        jQuery('.square-container div[data-id=' + v.TileID + ']').attr('data-content', v.PledgeContent);
        jQuery('.square-container div[data-id=' + v.TileID + ']').attr('data-smoke', v.isSmoker);
        jQuery('.square-container div[data-id=' + v.TileID + ']').attr('data-fb_uid', v.FBID);
        if (v.Lastname != null)
        jQuery('.square-container div[data-id=' + v.TileID + ']').attr('data-name', v.Firstname + ' ' + v.Lastname);
        else
        jQuery('.square-container div[data-id=' + v.TileID + ']').attr('data-name', v.Firstname);
      }
      reveal += 1;
    });
    //reveal = data.Pledges.length;
    //console.log(data.Pledges.length + ' ' + reveal);
    $('.changeMe').text(reveal + '/' + number_square);
  }
},
error: function () {
  console.log('An error has occured, please refresh page and try again');
}
});
```

On the day of the launch, there will be a number of users using the website simultaneously, so I was wondering how can I make sure the request is done automatically - every 30 seconds so the page always updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do the following which will run every 30 seconds..

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // code you want to run..
}, 30000);
```